# php sql subgroup list

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple code which gives me error. Could someone help me to explain what would be the best solution. I am not just interested the solution rather than the explanation as I have been struggling with this type of listing. I have googled it but I could not find a dummy explanation.

Many thanks

```
<?php
    // Run a Query
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM weblinks ORDER BY yeargroup ASC");
    $a=-1;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        if ($row['yeargroup'] == $a) {
            echo "<h2 class=\"class\">Year ".$row['yeargroup']."</h2>";
        } else {                    
            echo "<ul><li>";
            echo "<img src=\"" . $row['img'] . "\"/>";
            echo "<a href=\"".$row['weblink']."\">".$row['webname']."</a> - ".$row['weblink'];
            echo "<div class=\"text\">".$row['content']."</div>";
            echo "</li></ul>";
        }
        $a=$row['yeargroup'];   
    }
?>
```

fixed the typo error, thanks

This is how it should be

```
Year 1

Link1
Link2
Link3

Year 2

Link1
Link2
Link3

etc.
```

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: I cant get the h2 header at all

Comment: That's because you should be checking `if ($a == -1)`

Comment: I have yeargroup from 0 to 6 so I would like to list all the groups therefore -1 would not work

Comment: Debug it by printing out $a and $row[yearbook] immediately after your while statement. Then you shiuld be able to spot your logic error yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a = null;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    //check if $a is equal to the current yeargroup
    //if not, output the header and open the list
    if ($row['yeargroup'] <> $a) {
        echo "<h2 class=\"class\">Year ".$row['yeargroup']."</h2>";
        echo "<ul>";
    }

    echo "<li>";
    echo "<img src=\"" . $row['img'] . "\"/>";
    echo "<a href=\"".$row['weblink']."\">".$row['webname']."</a> - ".$row['weblink'];
    echo "<div class=\"text\">".$row['content']."</div>";
    echo "</li>";

    //check if $a is equal to the current yeargroup
    //if not, close the list and set $a to the yeargroup for the loop
    if ($row['yeargroup'] <> $a) {
        echo "</ul>";
        $a = $row['yeargroup'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi tried this as well but only the first h2 echoed and nothing else. I have different yeargroups from 0 to 6 so I need list them all when applies. Any idea? thanks

Comment: @AndrasSebestyen What does your result set look like?

Comment: I only got back the first h2 and no content.

Comment: @AndrasSebestyen I need to see what your result set looks like.

Comment: his is what i got:
Year 0

BBC Iplayer - http://bbc.do.uk
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempus ipsum et lectus tempus gravida eget a lectus. Aliquam consequat scelerisque eleifend. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; posuere.

Comment: @AndrasSebestyen You need to use two queries. One for the year, then one for the links.

Comment: This is where I am struggling to create 'nested' sql query through php. Is there any tutorial or explanation how to do that?

Comment: Please try my updated answer.

Comment: thanks a lot! first the else did mess up everything (either the title or the content) and yes it is bettter with the not equal. Thanks again

Comment: Hi only one thing is missing from your code if ($a <> null) echo "</ul>"; after the first IF.

Comment: I would recommend using a flag to determine whether to close the list and continue to the next header.

Comment: thanks for the advice, appreciate your help